# Simple Calendar with option for different months

Tags: c#, calendar, console-application

Here's the prompt: Write a program
that prints a calendar for one month. Input
consists of an integer specifying the first
day of the month (1 = Sunday) and an
integer specifying how many days are
in a month.

Here is a sample output of what it should look like:

```
    First day of the month 3 
    Number of days in the month 31

    Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday
                     1        2        3       4       5 
      6      7       8        9        10      11      12
      13     14      15       16       17      18      19
      20     21      22       23       24      25      26
      27     28      29       30       31
```

I've been working on it and here is what I have so far.

```
namespace Program_202t
{
   class Program
   {

     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        Console.Title = "Program 202t";

        Console.Write("Enter the first day of the month: ");
        int year = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter the number of days in a month: ");
        int month = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("\nSunday  Monday   Tuesday  Wedsnesday  Thursday  Friday  Saturday");
        if (year == 1)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 4);
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(i + "         ");


                if (((i) % 7) > 0)
                {
                }

                else
                {
                    Console.Write("\n");
                }
            }
            Console.Write("\b");
            for (int b = 11; b <= month; b++)
            {
                if (((b) % 7) > 0)
                {
                    Console.Write(b + "        ");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write(b + "\n");
                }

            }

        }
        if (year == 2)
        {
            //Console.SetCursorPosition(10, 4);
            for (int i = 1; i <= month; i++)
            {
                if (i == 1)
                {
                    Console.Write("         " + i + "         ");
                }
                else if (i > 1 && i < 11 && i != 6)
                {
                    Console.Write(i + "         ");
                }
                Console.Write("\b");
                if (i == 6)
                {
                    Console.Write(i + "\n");
                }
                if (i > 11 && i != 14)
                {
                    Console.Write(i + "       ");
                }
                if (i == 14)
                {
                    Console.Write(i + "\n");
                }


                /*if (((i) % 6) > 0)
                {
                }

                else
                {
                    Console.Write("\n");
                }
            }
            Console.Write("\b");
            //FIX!!!
            for (int b = 11; b <= month; b++)
            {
                if (((b) % 13) > 0 && b >13)
                {
                    Console.Write(b + "        ");

                }
                if (((b) % 20) > 0 && b <= 13)
                {
                    Console.Write(b + "        ");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("\n");
                }

            }*/

            }
            if (year == 3)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(20, 4);
                for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write(i + "         ");


                    if (((i) % 5) > 0)
                    {
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write("\n");
                    }
                }
                Console.Write("\b");
                for (int b = 11; b <= month; b++)
                {
                    if (((b) % 7) > 0)
                    {
                        Console.Write(b + "        ");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write("\n");
                    }

                }

            }
            if (year == 4)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write(i + "         ");


                    if (((i) % 7) > 0)
                    {
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write("\n");
                    }
                }
                Console.Write("\b");
                for (int b = 11; b <= month; b++)
                {
                    if (((b) % 7) > 0)
                    {
                        Console.Write(b + "        ");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write(b + "\n");
                    }

                }

            }
            if (year == 5)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write(i + "         ");


                    if (((i) % 7) > 0)
                    {
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write("\n");
                    }
                }
                Console.Write("\b");
                for (int b = 11; b <= month; b++)
                {
                    if (((b) % 7) > 0)
                    {
                        Console.Write(b + "        ");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write(b + "\n");
                    }

                }

            }
            if (year == 6)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write(i + "         ");


                    if (((i) % 7) > 0)
                    {
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write("\n");
                    }
                }
                Console.Write("\b");
                for (int b = 11; b <= month; b++)
                {
                    if (((b) % 7) > 0)
                    {
                        Console.Write(b + "        ");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write(b + "\n");
                    }

                }

            }
            if (year == 7)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write(i + "         ");


                    if (((i) % 7) > 0)
                    {
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write("\n");
                    }
                }
                Console.Write("\b");
                for (int b = 11; b <= month; b++)
                {
                    if (((b) % 7) > 0)
                    {
                        Console.Write(b + "        ");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write(b + "\n");
                    }

                }

            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


    }

}
```

Do any of you know what I am doing wrong for the years that aren't 1? One works fine, but the rest have various problems.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What various problems? That's a lot of code to go thru. can you reduce it to the area which you think is causing the issue?

Comment: The IF and FOR statements have the problem; I just included the whole thing for reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this do?

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Title = "Program 202t";

        Console.Write("Enter the first day of the month: ");
        int startingDay = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter the number of days in a month: ");
        int daysInMonth = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        List<string> daysOfTheWeek = new List<string>() {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};
        foreach (string day in daysOfTheWeek)
        {
            Console.Write($"{day,10}");
        }
        List<string> days = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < startingDay; i++)
        {
            days.Add($"{"",10}");
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < daysInMonth+1; i++)
        {
            days.Add($"{i,10}");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < days.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i%7!=0) {Console.Write(days[i]);}
            else {Console.WriteLine(days[i]);}                
        }

    }
```

Comment: Yes, that's perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Alrighty, i did a quick run through of the code and I see where you're issues are so I'll give you some tips on where to look.

For one, your code has logical issues revolving around the required formatting of the output. There are simpler ways to output the correct formatting. If you look at the [.NET String Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx) then look at formatting, you may find an easier way to do it.

Next, you have an issue with misaligned block endings so some of your code is never getting executed. I recommend you breakpoint your code at the first `if` statement and step through the code to understand the execution in runtime.

Lastly, I recommend clarifying your variable names a little bit. If the first input represent that day of the week, then perhaps use a variable name that represents it (for example `dayOfWeek`, but `month` doesn't do it for me). Also the number of days in the month could use a better variable name.

Please do ask questions if you need some more guidance. I'd be happy to help.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestions. Can you explain 1 and 2 a little more because I don't understand what they mean? Also, can you actually help me and change the code to what makes sense? Thanks!

Comment: Running your actual code, I can get it to print out for `year = 2` and `month=30` but there are issues in your logic for the formatting that result in the output being misaligned. This is likely going to cost you points on your assignment. Look into your logic and write it out on paper to see what the results will be until you understand it more. Once you understand it, making the code adjustments will be a little bit easier.

2nd, look at your `if` blocks and look at where they begin and end. 

I could help you with the code, but as a college teacher I feel like guiding is best right now.